# how to make a counter in linux?

Tags: linux, shell, sleep

I'm trying to write a script where I want to make a countdown of three seconds (probably with the sleep command), but every second I want to display the text "break".

After every second, I want to display a countdown next to the word "break", but the line of text should stay in place. The word "break" must stay in one place; only the number should change.

Comment: use `printf` with `\r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In bash, you can use a for loop, and the character `\r` to move the cursor back the the beginning of the line:

```
for ((i=3; i; --i)) ; do
    printf 'break %d\r' $i
    sleep 1
done
```

Comment: Never seen `\r` used like this, only seen `\r\n` Nice! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ANSI terminal control sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code). Like this:

```
# Save the cursor position
echo -en "\033[s";

for i in {3..1} ; do

    echo -n "break $i"
    sleep 1

    # Restore the cursor position
    echo -en "\033[u";

done

# Print newline at the end
echo
```

If you want the last `break 1` to disappear from screen then change the last line to

```
# Clear the line at the end
echo -en "\033[K"
```